# Extracting email addresses from user account in PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, data-structures

I need to map user accounts that I find on files in a file share to email addresses (in order to migrate them as a later step).

I am almost there, but I am getting the email addresses in a strange format, like this:

`@{EmailAddress=first.last@xx.xxxxx.com}`

How can I get it like a regular string variable instead? Like:
`"first.last@xx.xxxxx.com"`

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFilesPath -Force -Recurse

ForEach ($File in $Files)
{

    $createdDate = (Get-Item "$($File.Directory)\$($File.Name)").CreationTime
    $modifiedDate =  (Get-Item "$($File.Directory)\$($File.Name)").LastWriteTime

    $createdBy = ((Get-Acl -Path "$($File.Directory)\$($File.Name)").Owner).Split("\")[-1]

    $email = (Get-ADUser $createdBy -Properties EmailAddress) | select EmailAddress
    
   Write-host $email
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use either `(Get-ADUser $createdBy -Properties EmailAddress).EmailAddress` or `Get-ADUser $createdBy -Properties EmailAddress | Select-Object -ExpandProperty EmailAddress`. Those are equivalent.

Select-Object will display a property, but even if you select only one it will still leave it as a property of an object. To extract just the property value, you need to specify the `-ExpandProperty` parameter. When you do that, however, you can only specify one property to expand.

You can also really simplify your code. You're repeating yourself when you've already got most of the information you need.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFilesPath -Force -Recurse

ForEach ($File in $Files)
{

    $createdDate = $File.CreationTime
    $modifiedDate =  $File.LastWriteTime

    $createdBy = $File.GetAccessControl().Owner.Split("\")[-1]

    $email = (Get-ADUser $createdBy -Properties EmailAddress).EmailAddress
    
    Write-host $email
}
```

Also, you shouldn't need to specify `"$($File.Directory)\$($File.Name)"`. You can just specify `$File.FullName`.

One of the first things to learn about Powershell is some of the language introspection.

`$Files[0] | Format-List -Properties *` or `$Files[0] | fl *` will list all properties of an object.

`$Files[0] | Get-Member` or `$Files[0] | gm` will list the member functions of the object.

`$Files[0].GetType().FullName` will list the type of object. You can Google search and look at the .Net reference for the object class.